# How did the Latin past participle suffix -atus develop into modern French -é?

Tags: etymology, morphology, latin, french, romance-languages

How did the Latin past participle suffix -atus develop into modern French -é?

Considering the two following examples: modern French *état* ("state; status") and *été* ("been"). Both derives ultimately from the Latin past participle *status*. But while the former, as a noun, retains a somewhat faithful representation of the root word, the latter deviates for some reason. Compare cognates in Italian, Portuguese and Spanish which have perfect parallels: Italian *stato*, Portuguese and Spanish *estado* are the single form of both the noun and past participle.

On another note, considering the suffix *-té* of the unrelated noun *été* ("summer") which is on the other hand, regular, as it derives from the Latin suffix *-tas*.

Basically, the most straightforward routes would be Latin *-atus* > French *-at*, *-as* > *-é*. Yet the past participle ending *-é* doesn't follow these routes. Why?

Comment: But _été_ is surely from the oblique stem _aetat-_, so it is not an exception. And I don't understand your last paragraph: that is exactly the trajectory of the (1st conjugation) past participle.

Comment: @ColinFine: Vun-Hugh Vaw seems to be saying in the last paragraph that he thinks "atus" had a regular reflex of "at", and "as" had a regular reflex of "é".

Comment: @ColinFine My point was that the ending of the past participle should ideally be "-at" to be regular compared to those of other Romance languages (Italian "-ato", Portuguese and Spanish "-ado"), not "-é" as if it derived from the Latin noun ending "-as". And yet that's basically what it does.

Comment: @sumelic: I think you're right, I misinterpreted what the OP was saying. The answer to that one is that _-as_ is rarely the relevant ending. Most French (and Romance) nouns come from Latin obliques, not nominatives, and most Latin nouns in _-as_ have stem _-at-_ (as does _aetas_).

Comment: I haven't found a definitive answer, so I haven't posted an answer. But _-atum_ -> _-é_ is the regular development, and _-at_ is the exception which needs explanation. See for example [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_French#Lenition).

Comment: @ColinFine (and anyone else looking at this): I've posted a tentative answer over on [French SE](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/26305/6881)

Answer (score 6):

It is a fairly regular evolution.
Starting with the accusative ending *-átum*, we have the loss of final nasal. Then the accented /a/ in the open syllable transitioned slowly to open /ε/ (cf. *-arium* > *-aire*, *-alem* > *-el* but also *mare* > *mer*). Eventually the post-accentual vowel got lost (and the /t/ probably first got voiced intervocally, lenited to a fricative and then lost voicing word finally).

So from *statum*, there was something like *estεθ* at this stage (cf. Chanson de Roland, first strophe - *(Charles li reis) ad estet in Espaigne*). With the loss of word final consonant, the syllable opened and followed the rule of closed vowel in open syllable, becoming /e/.

*été* (summer) follows pretty much the same path from *aestas/aestatem*.

*état* (state) is the exception here and I bet it is not a direct descendant but rather an early borrowing from Latin.

Comment: You are most likely correct - before the loss of the final vowel, the original Latin /t/ got voiced to /d/ but also it most likely continued the lenition to a fricative as in Spanish or elsewhere in French (c.f. _sudor_ > _sueur_). With the final devoicing, this would produce /θ/, which would be even more likely to be further supressed.

Comment: Amateur here: It would seem to me that in all three examples, a metathesis takes place, and then the diphthongs *ai* and *ae* gradually become an umlaut-ed *a*, which then naturally morphs into an *e*. Same for *aestatem*. This does not the seem to be the case with *status, -um*, however. If anything, we should have had *étau(t)*.

Comment: It is because there is no metathesis - do not get confused by the historicising orthography of French where you have _-aire_ instead of _-ère_ simply because some scholars of old liked to make the written form more reminiscent of the Latin original (which in some cases they even determined incorrectly). There is no evidence of any _-aCem_ > _-aeC_ metathesis and there is quite overwhelming evidence against it (basically all the passive participles ending in _-atum_ still following the same course of evolution as you aptly noted yourself).